# clojure swank server opens public port?

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank

(This question has been downvoted, which I find strange. How have I offended?)

Am I right to think that running a swank server usually opens port 4005 to the world, not bound to localhost-only connections?

So anyone hacking in a café is not only allowing passers-by to execute arbitrary code on their computer, but is giving them a nice interface to do it with.

It appears that when I run a swank server with either 'mvn clojure:swank', or 'lein swank', or (swank.swank/start-server "/tmp/yo")

then I get something like (thanks Mike!):

```
$lsof -i -P
java      11693 john   13r  IPv6 6701891      0t0  TCP *:34983 (LISTEN)
```

and indeed I can connect from an emacs running on another machine on the same network.

```
(swank.swank/start-server "/tmp/yo")
```

If I start the server by hand, it produces the following output

```
Connection opened on local port  34983
#<ServerSocket ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=34983]>
```

Whereas:

```
(swank.swank/start-server "/tmp/yo" :host "localhost")
```

produces:

```
Connection opened on local port  40368
#<ServerSocket ServerSocket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=0,localport=40368]>
```

Which seems more like I was expecting.

Is there any good reason for doing this?

Any ideas on how it the more conventional ways of starting it could be persuaded to only accept connections from local processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally valid question.

After opening a slime server, you'll notice:

```
eames:~:% lsof -i -P | grep 4005
java      41477  mjd   33u  IPv6 0x0b8956d0      0t0  TCP [::127.0.0.1]:4005 (LISTEN)
```

The connection is listening on the local address at port 4005. This interface isn't exposed to the network, so other devices on the network can't connect to your slime server.

edit:

This was my result of starting swank using leiningen, which provides "localhost" as an argument to `swank.swank/start-server`. You may want to double check that the leiningen plugin is opening non-local ports.

You're right that swank opens the connection on every address if a host isn't explicitly provided. The relevant code is `swank.util.net.sockets/make-server-socket`, and this behavior is documented. I agree, it seems like the wrong default.

Comment: java      10561 john   14r  IPv6 6521448      0t0  TCP *:4005 (LISTEN)

Comment: That's a publicly exposed port. How are you starting swank?

Comment: mike, sorry for the super-terse response. was editing my original and somehow didn't notice that my copy and paste had gone into the comments. Thanks for the diagnostic!

Comment: Seeing the same thing: java      8578 john   43u  IPv6 597878      0t0  TCP *:4005 (LISTEN)
using $lein version
Leiningen 1.3.1 on Java 1.6.0_20 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
and the port is open, confirmed by connecting to it from emacs on a second machine.

Comment: Which version of swank are you using? You should have something like `:dev-dependencies [["swank-clojure" "1.2.1"]]` in your project.clj.

Comment: ah, mine says: [leiningen/lein-swank "1.1.0"]. will retry.

Comment: generating a new project with $lein new test gives (defproject test "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]) and indeed, lein swank from here seems to open a local port. Looks like the default has been changed recently. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using `swank-clojure.el`, you can add `:host \"localhost\"` inside the `format` string which controls how the server is started in `swank-clojure-init` (look for `"(swank.swank/start-server ...)\n\n"`) to have it listen on localhost only.

Answer (score 1):

it only accepts one connection so even if it is exposed to the world it stops listening once you connect.

Comment: and it's only a little annoying that it does not start listening when you disconnect (though i's much more secure this way) and it't really not a lot more work to restart it rather than having to remember to stop it when I finish.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the clojure-maven-plugin, version 1.3.4 was recently released which now start the swank server against localhost to prevent this problem.

This behaviour can be configured in your pom.xml file with:

```
<configuration>
  <swankHost>someotherhostname</swankHost>
</configuration>
```

or from the command line with:

```
mvn clojure:swank -Dclojure.swank.host=someotherhostname
```

Comment: It's wonderful that you've taken the trouble to close this loophole within a day of me noticing it. Well done Mark! I wish I could accept two answers!

Comment: I've tested the snapshot release (git clone followed by mvn install followed by modifying project pom.xml). It works a treat.